# WPF Binding on Nested ItemControls with Sub Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have the following xaml:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ResearchLanguageViewModel.Filters, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Type}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBox Text="Search...."></TextBox>
                <ItemsControl>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=Values}"></CheckBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

With the following objects/collection(s):

```
public class FilterViewModel
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> Values { get; set; }
}

public class ResearchLanguageViewModel
{
    public int FirmCount { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<FilterViewModel> Filters { get; set; } 
}
```

I'm trying to bind on the Filters property and the Type property comes out fine.  However, I am having trouble getting the Values collection of strings to show as a group of checkboxes. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here...

Comment: Thanks guys! Quick response!  Who should I award it to? Jo or Sa?  Sa answered first but Jo could use the points ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to bind `Values` to the `ItemsControl` not the `Checkbox`,

```
 <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Type}"></TextBlock>
    <TextBox Text="Search...."></TextBox>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Values}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding}"></CheckBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 2):

Bind your item controls, ItemSource property to values.

For a string, you won't even need a template. In your model, you have a collection of strings, so binding to a checkbox template does provide some UI enhancement but my betting is you want the checked status represented in the view model too.

You might want to consider creating an object to encapsulate your label and Checked status and defining your collection based on that.

```
public class CheckModel
{
    public string Label {get; set;}
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
}
```

Then bind your checkbox to:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Checked}" Content="{Binding Label}" />
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Please comment and not just -1

Comment: :) I take it very personally.

Comment: Despite providing a partially correct answer, that really should have just been a comment. If you look at upvoted answers on Stack Overflow, you'll see that they put far more effort into their answers. I'm trying to encourage you to do the same, and if you improve the quality of your answer, I'll happily remove this down vote... maybe even give an upvote. As a long time member, I'm just trying to keep the high standards found on this website. Single (or double) sentence answers are frowned upon here for that very reason. It's not about speed of answer here, it's about quality.

Comment: how will the string display in a `Checkbox` without a template? pretty sure it defaults to `TextBlock`

Comment: I think down voting a correct answer is not in the correct spirit, especially when a sentence or two is enough. Whilst a comment would suffice, this is not commentary, but an answer. I take on board your comments, however, and will provide a more comprehensive response.

Comment: You know what? That probably was a bit harsh, so I'll remove the downvote now anyway. However, I hope you do understand my point and leave more useful answers in future. Remember, the better the answer is, the more upvotes it'll get.

Comment: Hey, don't get carried away... it wasn't all correct. Ask yourself this... would your answer help more than the other answers? You know the answer is no. Anyway, I can't remove the down vote until you edit the answer. Stack Overflow's rules.

Comment: My answer was posted before the other answers. I agree it wasn't perfect, I have added detail to clarify my initially brief message. The nature of peer review is to expect critique. I respect and appreciate yours and take it on board.

Answer (score 2):

`Values` in your View Model is an array, and you are trying (I'm assuming) to create an array of `Checkboxes` with the values of each checkbox being the index value into that array.

In your model, you are passing in the array of values into the content of one single checkbox control.  What you need to do is bind the array to the parent's `ItemsSource` and bind the new value to the `Checkbox` control's content.  Something like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ResearchLanguageViewModel.Filters, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Type}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBox Text="Search...."></TextBox>
                <ItemsControl>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate ItemsSource={Binding Path=Values}>
                        <DataTemplate>                              
                            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Mode=TwoWay}"></CheckBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```